# Custom play-button trips on iOS video autoplay restriction

Tags: ios, html5-video

Video autoplay (including YouTubes autoplay=1) does not work on iOS Safari. That is thourougly documented by both Apple and a large number of blog posts.
This does however cause a problem with using custom controls for YouTube videos, that I can't find a definate yes/no answer for anywhere.
If I used a simple HTML5 video tag there would be no issue - but I would really rather not have to encode all the videos for all the different platforms.

What I need to accomplish is:

- A cover image is shown (flat PNG with a play icon on top).
- The user clicks the cover image, the image is replaced by a YouTube video that starts playing.

This is not autoplay from the users perspective, since it is initiated by a click. However on all non-Flash devices YouTube embeds are displayed in an iframe, causing the video to effectively be loaded and autoplayed (or at least, I think so).
Does anyone know of any workarounds for this problem?

This snippet illustrates the problem. It works in e.g. FireFox, but on iOS Safari it simple shows the loading indicator and then ends in a black screen.

If I add the "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" meta tag and fire up the site from the home screen, the videos play correctly.

```
<div id="movieContainer" style="width: 768px; height: 432px; border: 1px solid #cccccc;">Initializing player API...</div>

<div id="status">Initializing player API...</div>

<button onclick="player.playVideo();">Play</button>

<script>
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


var playerAPIIsLoaded = false;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()
{
    playerAPIIsLoaded = true;
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Player API initialized!";
}

var player = null;
function initMovie()
{
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Loading video..."

  player = new YT.Player(
    'movieContainer',
    {
        height: '432'
      , width: '768'
      , playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 2, 'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0 }
      , videoId: 'MwnZr4VJQPQ'
      , events: { 'onReady': function (event) { document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Video loaded!";/*event.target.playVideo();*/ } }
        }
    );
}

window.onload = initMovie;
</script>
```

Comment: iOS forbids all videos & audio to auto-play.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But since there is actually a click/user-interaction taking place, there could possibly be a workaround in this case.

Comment: iOS videos will be played ONLY when users actually "click" on the Play button.